# I'm trying to read a Bitmap file

Tags: c++, bitmap

I'm trying to read a grayscale Bitmap file using C++. Following is the code for getting all information about the file, as given on the wikipeadia page on [Bitmap file format](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format):

```
int main() {
    FILE *fptr;
    string fileName;


    cout<<"Please provide the name of the file: "<<endl;
    cin>>fileName;

    fileName = "Test Images/"+fileName+".bmp";

    fptr = fopen(fileName.c_str(), "rb");
    cout<<"FileName : "<<fileName<<endl;

    if(fptr == NULL){
        cout<<"File Not found"<<endl;
        getch();
        return -1;
    }
    unsigned char total[54];

    fread(total, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, fptr);

    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Type: "<< *(char*)&total[0x00]<<*(char*)&total[0x01] <<endl;
    cout<<"size: "<< *(int*)&total[0x02]<<endl;
    cout<<"offset: "<< *(int*)&total[0x0A]<<endl;
    cout<<"Info header size: "<< *(int*)&total[0x0E]<<endl;
    cout<<"Bitmap width: "<< *(int*)&total[0x12]<<endl;
    cout<<"Bimap height "<< *(int*)&total[0x16]<<endl;
    cout<<"Color planes: "<< *(int*)&total[0x1A]<<endl;
    cout<<"BPP: "<< *(short int*)&total[0x1C]<<endl;
    cout<<"Compression Method "<< *(int*)&total[0x1E]<<endl;
    cout<<"Raw bmp data size: "<< *(int*)&total[0x22]<<endl;
    cout<<"Horizontal Resolution: "<< *(int*)&total[0x26]<<endl;
    cout<<"Vertical Resolution: "<< *(int*)&total[0x2A]<<endl;
    cout<<"No of Color: "<< *(int*)&total[0x2E]<<endl;
    cout<<"No of imp colors: "<< *(int*)&total[0x32]<<endl;

    fclose(fptr);   
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Following is the out put, I'm getting for an image:
[program output for a grayscale image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D68xK.jpg)

It shows file has a size of 263224 bytes.
On calculating size, I'm getting offset + image size = 1078 + 512x512 = 263222 bytes only. Where am I missing rest 2 bytes?

Comment: *How* do you get the "size of the file"? How do you get the offset? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us (code says more than a thousand pictures).

Comment: What's your code reading the file?

Comment: How should we know o.O

Comment: Are you using the standard C `fseek` and `fread` functions? You need to be more specific. Right now what you're asking is impossible because we don't know how you're getting the file info, _especially_ the size.

Answer (score 0):

I would not worry about it, really. Your `1078 + 512*512 = 263222` calculation is correct. On various links I found via google (e.g. http://www.fastgraph.com/help/bmp_header_format.html or the German wikipedia-entry https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Bitmap#Dateikopf), it says that the `bfSize` entry in the header is "unreliable".

[edit: nevermind]